# How to write query for multiple statements in CASE if the condition is true?

Tags: mysql

Is this the correct way of handling multiple case statements for a true condition in MySQL?

```
 SELECT 
 CASE WHEN place='India' THEN `Order` END AS `Order`
 CASE WHEN place='India' THEN `Amount` END AS `Amount`
```

Or is there a better method for getting the Order and Amount if the condition is true?

Comment: If you want two different columns, then you have to make the case twice. You cannot split the result in two columns.

Comment: @JonTofte-Hansen Can you explain it with one example?

Comment: Scott has show how to do it in two columns. If you want both values in one column you can concatenate: CASE WHEN place='India' THEN concat(`Order` , ' ' ,  `Amount`) END AS `OrderAmount`.

Comment: No I need two columns, but the values are not accurate by using this query

Comment: You have to provide what you've got, what you have tried, and what the expected result should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN place='India' THEN 'Order' END AS 'Order',
CASE WHEN place='India' THEN 'Amount' END AS 'Amount'
from *table*
```

Case statements can only return one value; you have to execute two separate statements to get both values.

Comment: Is it ok if the condition statement repeated more than one time for several columns?

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'ok'. I personally don't know what the exact performance impacts are for having multiple case statements, but if you mean in terms of its functionality then yes; it will work.